# Специализация шаблонной функции для std::string

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонная функция, принимающая аргумент произвольного типа.
Хочется сделать специализацию этой функции для строк, но при этом строку передавать не по значению, а по const reference.

Например:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void f(T param)
{
    std::cout << "General" << std::endl;
}

template<> void f(const std::string& param)
{
    std::cout << "const std::string&" << std::endl;
}

void g(const std::string& str)
{
    f(str);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    f(str);
    g(str);
}
```

В данном примере, к сожалению, специализация не работает. Всегда вызывается неспециализированная функция.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать такую специализацию или перегрузку?

Comment: В общем случае лучше не использовать специализации шаблонных **функций**, а использовать перегрузки, т.к. такие специализации не участвуют в overload resolution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Правила дедукции шаблонных аргументов в обоих вызовах `f` дедуцируют `T == std::string`. Поэтому ваша специализация просто не подходит под дедуцированное значение `T`, т.е. будет использоваться "главный" шаблон. Если вы хотите "поймать" эти вызовы в специализации шаблона, то специализировать его придется для `std::string`, а не для `const std::string &`.

Перенаправить такие вызовы в вашу нынешнюю специализированную версию можно только "вручную", т.е. явным указанием шаблонного аргумента

```
f<const std::string &>(str);
```

А если вы сделаете именно *перегрузку* нешаблонной функцией для `const std::string &`, а не специализацию шаблона, то вызываться будет в обоих случаях именно перегруженная функция

```
void f(const std::string& param)
{
  std::cout << "const std::string&" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете просто в аргумент шаблона передать ссыльку, т.е.

```
template<typename T> void f(T& param)
{
    std::cout << "General" << std::endl;
}
```

Остальную часть оставлять как есть